# Ice form shout?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Does anybody know we're to find the ice form shout? I have found the first word but am having trouble finding the rest, someone please help I would be thankful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The three words of the [Ice Form](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Ice_Form) thu'um are as Iis, Slen, and Nus. They can be found in [Frostmere Caverns](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Frostmere_Crypt), [Mount Anthor](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Mount_Anthor) (a dragon lair), and [Saarthal](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Saarthal).

You might already have one of the words from Saarthal, as the main quests seem to require you to visit the college at various points. Which typically means starting the mage guild quest-line that includes an expedition to the tomb early on.